# JavaScript is breaking my theme in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, javascript, jquery, theme

I am having an unusual problem. I have a site in SharePoint 2013 I just stood up, and starting to experiment with JavaScript and jQuery. I am using one of the OOTB themes, not ready to monkey around with Master Pages and Themes just yet. So the only thing that makes my theme unique is the background images, there is no other customization.

Following the examples I found, here is how I add jQuery to a page:

- Add the jQuery source files to Site Assets.
- Create a .js file in Site Assets with my script, including references to source files.
- Create a new page.
- Add a Content Editor Web Part (CEWP) to the page.
- Set the Content Link of the CEWP to my .js file.
- Save and Publish.

Now, the script works perfectly fine, if I am logged in as an Administrator. But, if I visit my site as an Anonymous user, the script works, but the theme is not loaded. I get a plain white background. I get the same results whether in Chrome or IE 11.

To eliminate variables, I created a new page and added code to the .js file one line at a time. Here is the smallest script that breaks the theme:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/SiteAssets/scripts/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/SiteAssets/scripts/jquery.SPServices-2013.02a.js">
</script>
<label id="lblSomething">Here is something!</label>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        document.getElementById('lblSomething').innerHTML = "Here is REALLY something!";
    });
</script>
```

Now, if I remove the type="text/javascript" attribute from all three script tags, the theme is displayed correctly. But, of course, the script fails to execute.

I am not seeing any typical error messages. So, my question is two-fold: How can I display error messages that tell me why the theme is failing to load, and does anyone have a solution to this problem?

UPDATE:

Robert Lindgren suggests using a Script Editor Web Part instead. Fair enough, but it doesn't allow referencing a file (Content Link) like a CEWP does. So, I put just this code into a Script Editor Web Part (I remove the jQuery references) and I get the same behavior:

```
<label id="lblSomething">Here is something!</label>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('lblSomething').innerHTML = "Here is REALLY something!";
</script>
```

If I remove the type="text/javascript" attribute, which is HTML 5 standard, I don't get a broken theme, but the script doesn't work, either.

UPDATE 2:

Screenshots as requested. At this point, I have cleared out Edit Source and have JUST the label on the page:

```
<label id="lblSomething">Here is something!</label>
```

and a Script Editor Web Part with just the JavasScript. No jQuery, no referenced files, to help eliminate variables:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('lblSomething').innerHTML = "Here is REALLY something!";
</script>
```

Full disclousure, I am editing in Chrome and testing against IE, but that's just so I don't have to log out and in again. I have tested against both browsers, also cleared caches, it doesn't change the behavior.

When I am logged in as Site Administrator (Chrome).
[image]

When I am anonymous (IE 11). This is the same theme I see on all pages when I turn MDS off, FWIW. Also note that the JavaScript DOES execute.

[image]

UPDATE 3:
I also have an Office 365 site that I host. I recreated the same situation there, and I do NOT have the same problem. So this is something particular to my hosting company, or Microsoft does something different with Office 365 sites.

Comment: Well, my research indicated that using a CEWP was the way to go. I will go look for the page where I found that answer. But a CEWP allows a content link, and a Script Editor doesn't. More importantly, using a Script Editor, I get the same error (Updated my post).

Answer (score 3):

**Update 2**

Just using

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('lblSomething').innerHTML = "Here is REALLY something!";
</script>
```

without error handling will most likely cause runtime issues because if the code runs before the label is rendered it will throw a global JS exception causing the issues I already mentioned.

So, always use try/catch in JS and use the SP recommended way to execute JS on page load, see

[Can not load custom Js added on custom master page of SharePoint Online, on MDS enabled site](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/103443/can-not-load-custom-js-added-on-custom-master-page-of-sharepoint-online-on-mds)

and

[Loading jQuery in the Correct order](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/27819/loading-jquery-in-the-correct-order)

and

[sp.*.js are not registered to page for anonymous user in SharePoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/53559/sp-js-are-not-registered-to-page-for-anonymous-user-in-sharepoint-2013)

and

[Call JavaScript function on Page Render in o365](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/87628/call-javascript-function-on-page-render-in-o365/87658#87658)

**Update**

Also note that SP 2013 requires JavaScript to display the background image of a theme. So, any JavaScript error on your page might force SP to stop loading its own script.

Regarding your update:

As the name suggests, the Script Editor WebPart is for JavaScript, but your code is HTML tags with inline JavaScript. This might not work at all.

Regarding your original snippet, your code snippet consists of HTML with some inline JavaScript.

So, as a first step I'd rename the file to something like `mycustomsnippet.html` and reference this in your CEWP content link.

Also, SharePoint 2013 comes with an almost completely undocumented Ajax library called `mQuery`. This lib also uses the `$` moniker hence it might be possible that your are seeing a namespace clash, try to use the `jQuery` moniker instead of `$`.

Finally, don't use `document.ready` as it might interfere with SharePoint MDS (Minimal Download Strategy) and all the other built-in dynamic JavaScript features, like client-side rendering and the on-demand loading of SP internal JavaScript files.

It would help a lot if you could provide a screen capture, BTW, but I suspect that your HTML snippet is loaded as JavaScript and all browsers error out as the code contains HTML tags which are not valid JavaScript and cause SharePoint & the Web browser to cease loading the page at all.

Just a guess...

Comment: If you say so, but when adding a Script Editor, this is the text under "About the Part": "Script Editor
Allows authors to insert HTML snippets or scripts." So, Microsoft isn't very clear about it, either.

Comment: I went into "Edit Source" and cleared out all the web part code (seems deleting a web part isn't enough anymore). I put just the label in the source. I then added a script editor with the opening and closing script tag. I STILL get the white background, no theme.

Comment: Well, in this case I'm running out of ideas, sorry! BTW, did you try using jQuery intead of $?

Comment: As for your last paragraph, the script DOES execute, it's just that the theme isn't getting loaded. I have more than my share of JavaScript errors, but the result is the JavaScript doesn't execute, and the rest of the page loads fine. That is not the behavior I am seeing.

Comment: When I turn off JavaScript in Firefox for testing purpose, the background image doesn't load (because SP2013 requires JS to apply the background image) but the basic theme colors are applied, hence I asked for a screen capture to shed more light into this issue.

Comment: I am not using jQuery at all, to eliminate that as a variable. If I just have a <script></script> tag, the page loads fine with the theme. If I have a <script type="text/javascript"></script> tag, the theme is omitted.

Comment: Sorry, your original post used $(document).ready(function() { implying that you use jQuery. See my updated answer.

Comment: I started with jQuery, I eliminated it to narrow down the problem. The problem is occurring with nothing more than an empty <script type="text/javascript"></script> tag.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript"></script> might cause SP to puke either. Try to add at least one line of valid JS inside like var x = 0;

Comment: I did that. Same result. Could you update your answer to give the correct way to call JavaScript (not jQuery) on page load?

Comment: Done, added some links, took a moment...

Comment: I have tried all the links you provided. The JavaScript DOES fire, but the theme is still not loaded.

Answer (score 1):

I have re-created this scenario, using the exact same versions of the plugins with a custom theme and custom background image, and everything is working fine.

Perhaps you would want to take a broader look into your setup, as you may find outside variables, such as:

- all the pages and scripts, including the background images are publicly available
- double check your anonymous settings
- try [disabling MDS](http://www.wictorwilen.se/sharepoint-2013---introduction-to-the-minimal-download-strategy-mds)
- enable customerrors

**update**: disabling MDS shows the default theme.

adding a CEWP shows the default theme.

this could be a pattern that could lead to CEWP not being MDS compliant, which would explain the theme fallback on the particular page.

try to embed the scripts in the page itself instead of using a CEWP.

as a last resort, add the references to the theme into the master page

```
[MdsCompliant(true)]
```

Comment: I changed to an OOTB theme, same behavior.

Comment: The script is not referenced, it is manually entered into a Script Editor on the page. The page is accessible to Anonymous users, otherwise they wouldn't see the page at all.

Comment: I disabled MDS and now Anonymous users don't see any themes at all. That's the EXACT functionality I had with 2010! I had to manually update the master page to set a theme for Anonymous users. So, turning off MDS made things worse.

Comment: heres an interesting post from @sig a few years back. may have something useful http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/23281/spf2010-theme-not-getting-applied-for-anonymous-users

Comment: I turned MDS back on, now I get theme on every page, but still have the problem on my script page.

Comment: just the fact that disabling MDS changes the behaviour, tells me that something is wrong with it. perhaps you might consider referencing the theme in the master page as you did for 2010

Comment: I have done that, I moved the code to a Script Editor, and I still have the same problem.

Comment: I meant dont use in browser webparts

Comment: Scripting is automatically removed from the Web Page. I HAVE to put it in a web part.

Comment: you can edit the page in SPD and use additionalpagehead

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked permissions? Inconsistent behavior usually stems from permissions. Do anonymous users have read to your style libraries?

Comment: It's not permissions, they can see the theme on every OTHER page in the site. From what I can determine, it's something in the execution path between loading the theme and executing javascript. The script tag is stopping the theme from being loaded. But it's a bugger to troubleshoot.